# Minimizing code for scrapy - looping over URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape mma fighter stats and need some help minimizing this portion of my code. The links go from A to Z and there isn't a next page button to get to there.

I am sure there is a better way of doing this but I can't find it.

```
start_urls = [
    'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all',
    'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=b&page=all',
    'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=c&page=all',
    'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=d&page=all',
    'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=e&page=all',
    '....'

]

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all',
        'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=b&page=all',
        'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=c&page=all',
        'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=d&page=all',
        'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=e&page=all',
        '....'
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like...

```
def start_requests(self):
    links = []
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    for letter in alphabet:
       link = "http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=" + letter + "&page=all"
       links.append(link)

    for url in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Answer updated. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: thanks for the update, do I need to change the starts_urls [] section?

Comment: you can delete the start_urls section entirely. I dont think you needed it in your code anyway.

Comment: you are amazing thanks for your help. I knew there was an easier cleaner way of writing that.

Answer (score 1):

see [Using Scrapy to Scrape Directory Websites | Generate 26 start urls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrR_2vhaLfE)

You can use **string.ascii_lowercase** to create the alphabet